# scala 2.8 collections inconsistency?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.8

why the methods `transform` (in-place mutation version of `map`) and `retain` (in-place mutation version of `filter`) are defined on only `mutable.Map` but not on `mutable.Buffer` and `mutable.Set`? shouldnt all mutable collections support these methods?

Comment: One more thing. `immutable.MapLike` has the method `transform`, but not the method `retain`.

Comment: @michael: I have updated my answer to take into account that difference.

Answer (score 8):

The operations `retain` and `transform` of **[`Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_10.html)** are **about keys and values**, concepts which are not part of a [`Set`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_7.html) or a [`Buffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Buffer.html).

> A Map is an Iterable consisting of pairs of keys and values (also named mappings or associations).
>   The fundamental operations on maps are similar to those on sets.

But your operations are listed in:

> Mutable maps support ***in addition*** the operations summarized in the following table.

```
ms transform f
```

> Transforms all associated values in map `ms` with function `f`.

```
ms retain p
```

> Keeps only those mappings in `ms` that have a `key` satisfying predicate `p`.

---

[one-zero-zero-one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394691/one-zero-zero-one) comments:

> `retain` and `transform` are essentially in-place mutation versions of `filter` and `map` respectively and can be easily defined on `Set` and `Buffer`.
>   I don't see how they are `Map`-specific.

I would argue that `retain` and `transform` offer Map-specific implementations (in that their implementation specifically deals with keys and values) for features like the ones provided by [`map`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L189) and [`filter`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L231) from **[`TraversableLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html)**.

Implementing `transform` in `Set` and `Buffer` would add little value as it would simply deffer to `map`.

---

Note: [Michael Kebe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189058/michael-kebe) comments:

> One more thing. [`immutable.MapLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/MapLike.html) has the method `transform`, but not the method `retain`.

(as opposed to [`mutable.MapLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MapLike.html) which has both)

This seems however in-line with the nature of [transformation operations](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_10.html) if transform **produces a new map** by filtering and transforming bindings of an existing map.

Here is the [source code for transform](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//library/scala/collection/immutable/MapLike.scala#L113)

```
def transform[C, That](f: (A, B) => C)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[This, (A, C), That]): That = {
  val b = bf(repr)
  for ((key, value) <- this) b += ((key, f(key, value)))
  b.result
}
```

[Source code for `retain`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//library/scala/collection/mutable/MapLike.scala#L199), however, modified the current instance, which can only be compatible with Mutable objects:

```
/** Retains only those mappings for which the predicate
 *  `p` returns `true`.
 *
 * @param p  The test predicate 
 */
def retain(p: (A, B) => Boolean): this.type = {
  for ((k, v) <- this ; if !p(k, v))
    this -= k

  this
}
```

Comment: -1, `retain` and `transform` are essentially in-place mutation versions of `filter` and `map` respectively and can be easily defined on `Set` and `Buffer`. I don't see how they are `Map`-specific.

Comment: @one: the way they are documented involves Map-specific notions. But you are right, they could be extended to Set and Buffer. However, since `filter` and `map` are already there, may be this was less necessary for `Set` and `Buffer`.

Comment: @one-zero-zero-one: I have updated my answer to reflect on your comment.